# How to dynamically change input type

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

On my vue page I have three different inputs:

```html
<input
  id="id"
  class="flex-grow bg-white p-4 text-sm items-center focus:outline-none"
  type="text"
  name="id"
  v-model="id"
  placeholder="Enter your email or phone number..."
/>

<input
  v-show="phone"
  id="phone"
  class="flex-grow bg-white p-4 text-sm items-center focus:outline-none"
  type="tel"
  name="phone"
  v-model="phone"
  required
  placeholder="Enter your phone number..."
/>

<input
  v-show="email"
  id="email"
  class="flex-grow bg-white p-4 text-sm items-center focus:outline-none"
  type="email"
  name="email"
  v-model="email"
  required
  placeholder="Enter your email..."
/>
```

Now the first id field is the default field that shows on my page.  When the user starts typing I have a watcher to watch the value of "id".  If it's a string then it swaps the default text field for the email field.

If it's numeric then it swaps it for the tel field.

This is the watcher:

```js
watch: {
  id(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (this.startsWithLetter(newVal)) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.phone = null
        this.email = newVal
        this.$el.querySelector('#email').focus()
      })
    } else {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.email = null
        this.phone = newVal
        this.$el.querySelector('#phone').focus()
      })
    }
  },
},
```

Now this works however I've realised the focus simply does not work when the new field is swapped in.  The new field doesn't get focus and the soft keyboard hides itself.

Comment: Hm, several things here. What is `@input="$event.target.composing = false"` used for? What are your default values? What is `isString`? I'm not sure of the relationship of all of the 3 inputs here. Couldn't you make a computed property on the type of the field rather than creating several? Also, why do you want to focus it? (hint: `$refs` will be used rather than `querySelector` here) Also, by default every field is containing a string because this is how HTML works.

Comment: Have taken out the @input line, shouldn't have been there.  Have renamed isString to 'startsWithLetter' so it makes more sense. Thanks for your help. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly of what you're trying to achieve here. Seems a bit hard to understand for me.

Meanwhile, here is a simple example on how to have a dynamic input type depending of the content of the input.

```html
<template>
  <div>input: <input v-model="userInput" :type="phoneOrText" /></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userInput: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    phoneOrText() {
      return /\d/.test(this.userInput) ? 'tel' : 'text'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The input will be `text` if the input contains only text and will swap to `tel` if it contains any numbers thanks to the `/\d\` regex (any digit). I've chosen `password` for the screenshots because it is more visual but it can be anything. `tel` is working great on phone too and does not require any `focus()` or selection.

Not sure if it helps but right now, it seems a bit too cryptic for me to help you more.

[image]
[image]